# AIR app on iPad - start crash

Tags: ios, ipad, apache-flex, air, flex4.6

I created and installed an application for iPad according to the following instructions:
[Apple iOS development process using Flash Builder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS064a3073e805330f6c6abf312e7545f65e-8000.html)

However, when I run this simple application, for about a second the screen goes black and then returns to the normal iPad screen.
It almost seems as if the application is not running at all, but there's no error notification to be seen.
I'm really desperate...

testPad.mxml source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           backgroundColor="#A0F3FF" 
           width="100%" height="100%">
</s:Application>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Such a simple app shouldn't crash.  Which version of Flex are you using?  Which version of AIR?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Flex 4.6 (iOS MobileProject), AIR 3.5.0.1060

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a Mac, try opening xcode while starting the debugger. You can access the log files of the device that way.